# MySql - Missed event schedule

Tags: mysql, events, scheduling

I am trying to use mysql event schedule in my application, I have not use it before so i have some confusions.

I want to know if my computer is off on the schedule date, then schedule will continue on next day, after starting my computer?

Like:

my schduled is for beginning at every month (no predefined time set)
if in the above date my computer/Server is off, 
will mysql continue scheduled event in next day after turning on my computer/server?

If no, then please suggest a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmmmm, have you looked at something like this?

[MySQL: Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

... or:

[How to create MySQL Events](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)

... or even: [MySQL :: MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual: 19.4.1. Event Scheduler Overview](19.4.1. Event Scheduler Overview)?

Also please keep in mind that SQL DBMS **servers** are written with the rather strong presumption that they will be kept up and operating 24 hours per day with only brief periods of downtime for maintenance or repairs.  There is generally very little consideration for operation on machines which are shutdown at night and while not in use.

If you simply store a table of dates and events then your can simply query that table for events which have passed or are upcoming within any range you like ... and you can run the program(s) containing those queries (and performing any appropriate activities based on the results) whenever you start you computer and periodically while it's up and running.

These links refer to a feature of MySQL which is designed to have the server internally execute certain commands (MySQL internal commands, such as re-indexing, creating/updating views, cleaning tables of data which "expires" and so on.  I don't know if a MySQL server would attempt to execute all events which have passed during downtime, though it should only be a little bit of work to follow the tutorial, schedule some event for some time (say 15 minutes after the time you expect to hit [Enter]) ... then shutdown your computer (or even just the MySQL server) and go off to lunch.  Then come back, start it up and see what happens.

The scheduled event could be something absurdly simple, like inserting the "current" time into some table you set up.

Comment: Pretty bad answer as it doesn't answer (i.e. yes or no) the question asked. Seems to go off on detailing workarounds unrelated to the MySQL event scheduler altogether. Also the first link is no longer available.

Comment: Pretty ironic that the only attempt at an answer, the one chosen as "best" by the original querent, is voted down twice (with only one comment).  Voted down as many times as the original question was voted up.  ... and the allegedly broken link seems to resolve to a page linking to updated information (not really broken, just not particularly elegant).  :(